# SVM decision function: visualizing class separation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

in order to visualize the separation of the two classes by a `linearSVC`, I'm using a plot (defined in the function below)

```
def show_linearSVC_class_separation(linearSVC: 'LinearSVC', X_test, y_test):
    y_decision_score = linearSVC.decision_function(X_test)

    # getting the score of the truly positive individuals
    y_positive_decision_score = y_decision_score[y_test == 1]

    # getting the score of the truly negative individuals
    y_negative_decision_score = y_decision_score[y_test == 0]

    # counting the distribution of each score value in each class
    positive_count = Counter(y_positive_decision_score)
    negative_count = Counter(y_negative_decision_score)

    # sorting the decision scores to draw a good curve 
    y_positive_decision_score = np.sort(list(positive_count.keys()))
    y_positive_distribution = [positive_count[key] for key in y_positive_decision_score]
    y_negative_decision_score = np.sort(list(negative_count.keys()))
    y_negative_distribution = [negative_count[key] for key in y_negative_decision_score]

    # the alpaha is useful to see the overlaping area between the two classes
    plt.fill_between(y_positive_decision_score, 0, y_positive_distribution, color='blue', alpha=0.5, hatch='')
    plt.plot(y_positive_decision_score, y_positive_distribution, color='blue', marker='.')
    plt.fill_between(y_negative_decision_score, 0, y_negative_distribution, color='red', alpha=0.5, hatch='')
    plt.plot(y_negative_decision_score, y_negative_distribution, color='red', marker='.')


    plt.legend(['True_positives', 'True_negatives']).draggable()
    plt.xlabel('SVM decision_function values')
    plt.ylabel('Number of data points')
    plt.show()
```

but, the result is ... pretty ugly, juge by yourself: [image: exemple of a visualization using the function above]

I think it's because there is a lot of `decision_value`s that have a counting of one. Maybe an histogramme is the way to go. how can I bucket the `decision_values` in intervals and count the data points that belong to each interval ?
  I need the intervals to have the same length, exemple (length = 1) :

```
interval  || counting
[-7 ; -6] -> 20
]-6 ; -5] -> 30
....
] 5 ; 6] -> 10
```

Or maybe, there is another way to visualize binary class separation.

to do the visualization, I took inspiration form this blog article [Roc curve demonstration](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/10/05/roc-curve.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking around (matplolib and numpy documentation), I finally decided to try to use an histogramme to visualize the class séparation (knowing that I'm working on a multidimensional vector space, `~200k` dimensions).
  here is the function

```
''' Plots the seperation plane 
      Args:
           LinearSVC: An LinearSVC instance that was previously fitted (.fit())
'''
def show_linearSVC_class_separation(linearSVC: 'LinearSVC', X_test, y_test):

    y_decision_score = linearSVC.decision_function(X_test)

    # getting the score of the truly positive individuals
    y_positive_decision_score = y_decision_score[y_test == 1]

    # getting the score of the truly negative individuals
    y_negative_decision_score = y_decision_score[y_test == 0]

    # get the (min-1) and the (max +1) scores to be sure to include all the scores in the intervals of the histogramme
    _, min_positive = np.modf(y_positive_decision_score.min() - 1)
    _, max_positive = np.modf(y_positive_decision_score.max() + 1)
    positive_bins = np.arange(min_positive, max_positive + 1)

    # get the (min-1) and the (max +1) scores to be sure to include all the scores in the intervals of the histogramme    
    _, min_negative = np.modf(y_negative_decision_score.min() - 1)
    _, max_negative = np.modf(y_negative_decision_score.max() + 1)
    negative_bins = np.arange(min_negative, max_negative + 1)

    # plot the two histograms, alpha (the transparency) is for the overlapping areas
    plt.hist(y_positive_decision_score, bins=positive_bins, alpha=0.5, label='True positives', color='b')
    plt.hist(y_negative_decision_score, bins=negative_bins, alpha=0.5, label='True negatives', color='r')

    plt.xlabel('SVM decision_function values')
    plt.ylabel('Number of data points')
    plt.show()
```

Here is the result for the same example in the question:

[image: svm class separation]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
''' Plots the seperation plane 
    Args:
        LinearSVC: An LinearSVC instance that was previously fitted (.fit())
'''
def show_linearSVC_class_separation(linearSVC: 'LinearSVC', X_test, y_test):

    # get the separating hyperplane
    w = clf.coef_[0]
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
    xx = X_test
    yy = y_test

    # plot the parallels to the separating hyperplane that pass through the
    # support vectors
    b = clf.support_vectors_[0]
    yy_down = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])
    b = clf.support_vectors_[-1]
    yy_up = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])

    # plot the line, the points, and the nearest vectors to the plane
    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
    plt.plot(xx, yy_down, 'k--')
    plt.plot(xx, yy_up, 'k--')

    plt.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1],
                s=80, facecolors='none')
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.show()
```

This should generate a similar plot to this:
[image]

Comment: it's a very explanatory visualization, but in my case I can't do that, because the vector space on which I'm working has many dimensions ~ 200K not only 2

Comment: You could try using PCA/tsne for dimensionality reduction. If you still want to keep your original solution look at np.historgram(). the 'bins' argument is what you called 'sequences'.

Comment: the darwback of using PCA-like methods is to lose the meaning (interpretation) of each dimension. I need to do the interpretation (exemple, which dimension leads most to that class for a given data point ...). I'll have a look at `np.histogram`